# How to get smooth shading with bufferGeometry in three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making a cube sphere with LOD, and I ran into a little problem the normal that I was generating is by this code block.

```
// VectorVertices is an array of Vector3
let VectorNormals = new Array(this.VectorVertices.length);

for (let i = 0; i < VectorNormals.length; i++) {
    VectorNormals[i] = new THREE.Vector3();    
}

for (let i = 0; i < this.Triangles.length; i += 3) {
    let vertexIndexA = this.Triangles[i];
    let vertexIndexB = this.Triangles[i + 1];
    let vertexIndexC = this.Triangles[i + 2];

    let pointA = this.VectorVertices[vertexIndexA];
    let pointB = this.VectorVertices[vertexIndexB];
    let pointC = this.VectorVertices[vertexIndexC];

    pointB.sub(pointA);
    pointC.sub(pointA);
    let vertexNormal = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(pointB, pointC).normalize();

    VectorNormals[vertexIndexA].add(vertexNormal);
    VectorNormals[vertexIndexB].add(vertexNormal);
    VectorNormals[vertexIndexC].add(vertexNormal);
}

for (let i = 0; i < VectorNormals.length; i++) {
    VectorNormals[i].normalize();
    this.Normals.push(VectorNormals[i].x, VectorNormals[i].y, VectorNormals[i].z);
}
```

The `this.Normals` is then set to a `bufferGeometry`. I am creating the mesh with `MeshPhongMaterial`.

The **normals** between the **neighbouring faces** weren't calculated properly, and I don't what's going wrong. I apologize for my grammar. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Showing my image problem [This is the result I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dypcs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to make a smooth sphere, but you are assigning all of the normals of a triangle to the value of the face normal, which is what you're calculating by subtracting and crossing the vertex values. (Note: You may need to be careful regarding the direction of the crossed vector! Ensure it's pointing in the same direction as your original vertex vectors!)

To make a smooth surface, the normals of *adjoining vetices* need to be the same. So if you have two triangles:

```
A -- C
|  / |
| /  |
B -- D
```

Then to make the transition from `ABC` to `DCB` a smooth one, the normals at `B` and `C` must be the same. In the case of a sphere, they should also be the average of all surrounding face normals, which ensures a smooth transition in all directions.

*Actually* for a sphere, if the vertices all originate from the geometric origin, then all you have to do is normalize the vertex value, and that is the normal for that vertex.

Comment: BufferGeometry takes vertexNormal not face normal!.

Comment: @AnnAnjell I know. You are computing the face normal and assigning it to each vertex index of the triangle. What you want is _vertex normals_ that are _averages_ of the _face normals_ of the surrounding triangles. The easiest way to do that is to simply normalize the vertex value, because it is inherently perpendicular to the surface you are trying to create.

Comment: Basically I have to find the triangle index that is sharing with neighboring faces and average them.

Comment: @AnnAnjell Have a look at how `.computeVertexNormals()` works: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/BufferGeometry.js#L637L727